# for loop in r not working

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

We have a vector of vectors

```
s = c(c(7,6,8,5,9),c(3,2,4),c(6,5,7))
```

Why does this output the correct values to console

```
mean(s[1])
mean(s[2])
mean(s[3])
```

while the following yields nothing?

```
for (i in 1:3) {
   mean(s[i])
}
```

Comment: Because you don't print it, try `for (i in 1:3) print(mean(s[i]))`

Comment: @DavidArenburg that did the trick. thank you. akrun, thanks for making me aware

Answer (score 1):

By using `c`, we are concatenating the three `vectors` to a single `vector`.  So, the mean of `s[1]` or `s[2]` or `s[3]` will be mean of a single element instead of the vector.  i.e.

```
s = c(c(7,6,8,5,9),c(3,2,4),c(6,5,7))
s[1]
#[1] 7
s[2]
#[1] 6
s[3]
#[1] 8
```

But, if we assume that you have a list of `vectors`

```
 s <- list(c(7,6,8,5,9),c(3,2,4),c(6,5,7))
```

You can get the mean of list elements using `sapply`

```
 sapply(s, mean)
 #[1] 7 3 6
```

Based on the `for` loop code, if you use `[` instead of `[[` for the list

```
  for(i in 1:3){ print(mean(s[i]))}
  #[1] NA
  #[1] NA
  #[1] NA
  #Warning messages:
 #1: In mean.default(s[i]) :
 #argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

  for(i in 1:3){ print(mean(s[[i]]))}
  #[1] 7
  #[1] 3
  #[1] 6
```

For storing the output, we can create a new object `Out`

```
  Out <- vector('numeric', length(s))
  for(i in 1:3) Out[i] <- mean(s[[i]])
  Out
  #[1] 7 3 6
```